# Save user selection from a New Form

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I will generate a PDF with 3 possible themes so I need to show the user a form with 3 radio buttons to pick one.

On my Form1

With the line

```
SelectedTheme = ChooseTheme()
```

I call this Function

```
Private Function ChooseTheme() As String
    Dim formChooseTheme = New ChooseThemeForm()
    formChooseTheme.Show()
    Return ChooseTheme
End Function
```

The Form ChooseTheme() is the one with the 3 radio buttons and one cmd Button with this code:

```
Public Class ChooseTheme
Private Sub cmdChoose_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdChoose.Click

    If optNormal.Checked = True Then Theme = "Normal"
    If optElegante.Checked = True Then Theme = "Elegant"
    If optModerno.Checked = True Then Theme = "Modern"
    Me.Close()
End Sub
End Class
```

**But I can't make it work. I'm confused about where and how to define (DIM) the Theme or/and ChooseTheme variable. As a Public variable on the Form1 ?**

Comment: It's not really clear to me what the issue is here.  Is there some specific way in this the code you've written doesn't work?  "I can't make it work" isn't really descriptive.  If you're just wondering where to define a variable, you'd define it in whatever scope it's needed.  A method, a class, etc.

Comment: @Davis Thanks, now I renamed all the forms and variables and following Plutonix tips I'm trying to use dialog

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In part, you might be confused because there is a form class and also a function named `ChooseTheme`.  The function appears to be flawed since the function return value is never set.

If there are only three selections, I'd try to fit a ComboBox on the first form somewhere to prevent having to use a new form for such a small job.  Another alternative would be a menu item that is checked.

---

To use a form, you should probably show the theme selector as a dialog so the user cannot proceed until something is picked.  That way you can be sure you know when they have made a selection and it allows them to cancel/abort.

#### Dialog Form

In the ThemeSelector form, you need to add a property to expose their selection:

```
Public Property SelectedTheme As String = "Default"
```

Since you indicated radio buttons, initialize the property to match the default option.  Set the value from what they pick.

Since it is a Dialog, you also need to add `Ok` and `Cancel` buttons to the form to indicate how they exit.  Set the `DialogResult` property for them to `DialogResult.Ok` and `DialogResult.Cancel` respectively.

#### Using the Dialog

```
' local var to hold the current theme
Private PDFTheme As String
...

' code to get selection
Using dlg As New frmThemeSelector
    If dlg.ShowDialog() <> DialogResult.Cancel Then
        PDFTheme = dlg.SelectedTheme
    End If
End Using
```

Note also that a form shown using `ShowDialog` doesn't not automatically disposed when it is closed, you need to do that.  The code above uses a `Using` block to dispose of it.  This can be important if you want [old data settings cleared when you use it again](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29658242/1070452).

I would also suggest using a `PDFStyle` Enum for the variable rather than a string.

Comment: My mistake again!!! Your code works perfect.
It was my mistake because I did not know you need to set up the button on the form Dialog.Result = OK
Thanks again and apologize for any inconvenience

Comment: "Since it is a Dialog, you also need to add Ok and Cancel buttons to the form to indicate how they exit. Set the DialogResult property for them to DialogResult.Ok and DialogResult.Cancel respectively." Great adition for newbies like me. Now your answer is a complete mini tutorial. :)